# Compresse file with preserve modified time stamp

Tags: python, gzip

I'm stuck with setting up file time stamp, also as per python [gzip document](http://www.afpy.org/doc/python/2.7/library/gzip.html) , the syntax not working like `gzip.GzipFile(filename=outputfile,mode='wb',compresslevel=9,mtime=ftime)` , but when I used `gzip.GzipFile(outputfile,'wb',9,mtime=ftime)` it's working but except time stamp.

```
def compresse_file(file,ftime):
        data = open(file,'rb')
        outputfile = file +".gz"
        gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(outputfile,'wb',9,mtime=ftime)
        gzip_file.write(data.read())
        gzip_file.flush()
        gzip_file.close()
        data.close()
        os.unlink(file)
```

Here is output :

```
root@ubuntu:~/PythonPractice-# python compresses_file.py
Size      Date      File Name
5 MB      30/12/13  test.sh
Compressing...
test.sh 1388403823.0
file status after compressesion
5 kB      31/12/13  test.sh.gz
root@ubuntu:~/PythonPractice-# date -d @1388403823.0
Mon Dec 30 17:13:43 IST 2013
```

Comment: You really do that as `root`?!

Comment: @glglgl yes.. it's test machine.. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gzip#gzip.GzipFile), the `mtime` argument is the timestamp that is written to the stream, it doesn't affect the timestamp of the created gzip file. This is the timestamp the decompressed file will have if decompressed using `gunzip -N`.

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import gzip
>>> ts = datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 12, 13, 14).timestamp()
>>> zf = gzip.GzipFile('test.gz', mode='wb', mtime=ts)
>>> zf.write(b'test')
>>> zf.flush()
>>> zf.close()
```

And decompressed:

```
$ gunzip -N test.gz
$ stat -c%y test
2010-11-12 13:14:00.000000000 +0100
```

If you want the created gzip file to have a specific timestamp, use [os.utime](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os#os.utime) to change it:

```
...
st = os.stat(file)
...
os.utime(outputfile, (st.st_atime, st.st_mtime))
...
```

Comment: GNU `gzip` command preserve same timestamp as source file, that what I'm looking for, but still same issue, your solution also not working

Comment: it works fine for me. could you describe more in detail how the result deviates from what you expect? what timestamp changed how?

Comment: thanks, finally I've used `utime` but still `gzip` not working here is full code https://github.com/rahulinux/PythonPractice-/blob/master/compresses_file.py