# How to gzip file and preserve timestamp on linux

Tags: python, gzip

I been searching all over the internet but I am unable to find how to use python to gzip a log file and preserve the log file timestamp. I looked at gzip function that python provides but because it reads the data in and then outputs it, it overrides the timestamp of the file. I need it to behave exactly as if I ran a linux gzip command against a file. Is there any way to do this?

```html
    try:
      f_in=open(file,'rb')
      f_out=gzip.open(file + '.gz','wb')
      f_out.writelines(f_in)
      f_out.close()
      f_in.close()
    
      # delete copy that gzip creates during gzip process
      os.unlink(file)

    except IOError, e:
      print "Cant Gzip %s: File not found " % file
```

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856987/python-gzip-compresse-file-with-preserve-modified-time-stamp

Comment: That code uses specific timestamp where they manually put it in. I need to have the script pickup the timestamp of the file before it was gzipped and keep that timestamp after gzipping.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html):

> The *mtime* argument is an optional numeric timestamp to be written to the stream when compressing. All **gzip** compressed streams are required to contain a timestamp. If omitted or `None`, the current time is used. This module ignores the timestamp when decompressing; however, some programs, such as **gunzip**, make use of it. The format of the timestamp is the same as that of the return value of `time.time()` and of the `st_mtime` attribute of the object returned by `os.stat()`.

Comment: Here is the code that I have. How can I implement the mtime functionality into it so that it will keep the timestamp of the file before it was gzipped and have the same timestamp for after it was gzipped without passing the time manually. Basically I need it to act in the exact same way as gzip acts when you are compressing files on linux.

Comment: Also I am using python 2.6.6. I dont think mtime is available in that version. Is there any other work around for this?

https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/gzip.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 2.6, the zlib module has no possibility to tweak the mtime that is written into the gz file. You are left with only two ways :

- upgrade to Python 2.7, use stat/fstat to get the mtime of the original file and write it into the gz file
- use the gzip utility of the Linux system through the subprocess module.

Comment: Thanks Serge! I figured I might not have many options left. I am going to try and use a subprocess and see how it goes before upgrading everything.